# Generate APK using IBM Mobile First Platform

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am running MFP version - **7.1.0.00.20161118-2217**.
I have successfully built the .WLAPP file.

When working on site (connected to my DEV workstation via USB), we could do a

> mfp cordova run

and it would find all the devices and push the APK to the device.
I am working remotely now. (There is no way to connect the USB to the remote host)

When I run "mfp cordova run", I get the output :

> no android devices found. cordova will attempt to discover 
>       an emulator...
>       Could not find list of devices using: cordova run --list
>       Attenpting to run against default virtual device
>       Cordova config.xml currently configured with:

How do we generate an APK when no device is connected via USB? 
I have also tried running the following command:

> mfp cordova run --platform android

But this also does not generate an APK.
I appreciate any guidance or documentation regarding this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Building an apk is not related to MFP or CLI or Cordova.
It is related to Android Studio or using ADT command line tool to create.

Therefore Install either of them and use the provided tooling within those, to create an .apk.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the question is not about building an APK. The workaround for me was to get it built by someone who could connect a device and use mfp push. But would it be possible to use mfp to generate the APK (it may call other Android native methods) without having the device connected.